# Can I set a base route in react-router

Tags: react-router

Assuming my app's base url is *example.com/app*

Is it possible to set a base route in react-router so instead of writing all routes as

```
/app/a
/app/b
/app/c
```

I can just specify them as

```
a
b
c
```

I tried the below example I found in the [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md) but it wouldn't work (page would display nothing). Maybe it's because I'm using react-router@3.0.0-alpha.1, or I'm doing something wrong.

```
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHistory } from 'history'

const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: '/app'
})

const Root = ({store}) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path='/' component={App}>
                ...
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Please post an answer if yes.

Comment: @Learner nope. I gave up and started typing routes in full, and actually found it to be cleaner.

Comment: Really? There is no easy solution for this? I have searched and tried some ideas without any luck (but then I am a newbie).

Answer (score 168, accepted):

With the newest [react router (v4)](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) you can easily do this

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar">
  <Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/today">
</BrowserRouter>
```

or if you want it to be dynamic,

```
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL} >
  <Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/today">
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with dynamic path fields? Like `/calendar/:year/:month/:day/event` where it could be, for example, `/calendar/11/4/21/event`

Comment: why not put the `:year/:month/:day/event` part in the Link to=?

Comment: Important to point out here that the docs seem to be wrong about the correct usage of the <BrowserRouter> tag. A self-closing tag as seen in the docs will have no effect. You need to wrap your <BrowserRouter> tag around all your <Link>s and other routing tags. The example should read: <BrowserRouter basename="/calendar">
<Link to="/today"/><Link to="/tomorrow"/> ... </BrowserRouter>

Comment: this does not seem to work anymore unfortunately

Comment: @Madeo can you provide a new answer? I’ll redirect

Comment: `BrowserRouter` somehow did not work for me, I had to use  the `createBrowserHistory`'s API and remove `<BrowserRouter></...`

Comment: @Madeo I use the same approach as you do, but I find that `Route` component with trimmed path value will navigate to 404 route

Answer (score 20):

If you want to use `<Router />`, that give you access to history object, allowing you to change page through `history.push('/my-path')` method directly from js. You will face the issue that BrowserRouter does not have `history` prop available, and Router does not have `basename` available.

The solution is the following:

```js
const App: React.FC = () => {
  // do not put a slash at the end of the basename value.
  const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: '/your-base-name' });

  return <Router history={history}>
           ...
         </Router>;
}
```

> The base URL for all locations. If your app is served from a sub-directory on your server, you’ll want to set this to the sub-directory. A properly formatted basename should have a leading slash, but no trailing slash

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

Answer (score 3):

With React Router v6, it is recommended to use [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.14.2/routers/create-browser-router) for web projects, as it works with data APIs.

Pass an options object as the second argument to `createBrowserRouter`  to configure the [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.14.2/routers/create-browser-router#basename).

For example:

```js
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    { path: '/', element: <HomePage /> }
    /* other routes... */
], { basename: '/app' });

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

Comment: I tried this but got some errors. The first is`useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.` and the second is `useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component`. I am calling `useLocation` but `useRoutes` is coming from outside of my code. I looked at the documentation but don't see anything that shows how to migrate away from this. Any resources you can point us to?

Answer (score 0):

**Add to package.json this:**

> `"homepage" : "your-base-url"`