# Implementing relative paths on github.io/project in React

Tags: reactjs

is possible to implement relative paths on https://name.github.io/project in React for gh-pages, using React Router, as I receive errors. 
I used `import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';` and `export default withRouter(componentName);` to forward routing props from Router to targeting component, and I receive them.
I tried implemented like this Links:

```
<li><Link to={{pathname: this.props.match.url + '/new-post'}}>New Post</Link></li>
```

and used this modality this.props.match.url to obtain current path, but I receive errors.

Has anybody some suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a matching <Route/>?

Comment: @mhatch what do you mean by a matching <Route/>? Did I implemented the same: pathname: this.props.match.url + '/new-post' in <Route/>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be configured in react router history:

`history.js`

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: 'project',
});

export default history;
```

Comment: Where do I put REACT_APP_TEST_HOMEPAGE=http://name.github.io/project? and where should I import history.js, I suppose in component where the links are located?

Comment: You don´t need to use the env, you can use a string, I personally did that in a create react app and my env where in `.env``. `history` is the core library react-router use to handle history. You should read about `browserHistory`, ` hashHistory`,`memoryHistory`. History should be passed to your router/switch

Comment: Have you any resource for learning browserHistory and hashHistory? I found this on you tube? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdUyEou0LHg

Comment: What about [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) and [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) documentation?

Comment: My package.json file was already set to "homepage": https://name.github.io/project. I installed npm history, I copied your history file in my history.js file. Made in it let siteName = 'https://name.github.io/project'; Replace in history.js  process.env.REACT_APP_TEST_HOMEPAGE with process.env.siteName, saved, imported history.js in app, where my router is located, and included in  <Router history={history}>it's not working. Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https:' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://name.git..

Comment: I though you were looking for hint, so now I have updated my answer and I also give you the link to the [basename](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#using-a-base-url) documentation.

Comment: No, I was looking for an answer :) For me it's not working, I think it's an silly error of course :) I imported at the end import history from './history'; in App.js file where is my Router. Then I made history as property in Router <Router history={history}>, and nothing happens. NavLinks are not functioning.

Comment: This should be enough to help you out, prepare a reproduction so you can get help. Use codesandbox.io and a hashHistory

Comment: Ok, I will append it on sandbox, and share here. Why to use hashHistory instead of browserHistory?

Comment: Dimitri here is the link to sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/m351vnzz8y. , header menu is not functioning. I have imported history in App.js file with import history from "./history". In <Router> like this <Router history={history}>.I receives props with this modality:  to={{ pathname: props.match.url + "/name" }} in MenuHeader component by using withRouter HOC.

Comment: To sum up, what you need is a router configured for the base path `/project`, this means a <Link to="/test" /> should bring to `/project/test`. You don't need to set the full path when setting the base. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196448/can-i-set-a-base-route-in-react-router

Comment: Done, by injecting the basename into router. Thanks, Dimitri. Was it possible to do the same via history file? with Router v.4?