# Why is react-router not picking up a route that is not matched exactly when "exact" is not turned on?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following situation:

```
render() {
    let redirectRoute = window["reactRoute"];

    if (redirectRoute !== undefined) {
        window["reactRoute"] = undefined;
        return <Redirect to={redirectRoute} push={true} />;
    }

    return (
        <div className="otherContentContainer">
            <Route path="/validation" render={() => <p>TestRender</p>} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

The listed snippet above is a boiled down and simplified version of the affected `render()` in my case.

What's going on here is the following: My ASP.NET backend server returns a view which contains a subroute in `window["reactRoute"]` (This is something I came up with to get around the client-server routing problem with ASP.NET & React routing).

It then properly redirects to the following URL:

```
/Logon/validation/success
```

After the redirect is successful, the redirect part is not relevant anymore and I try to render certain components, in this case a simple `<p>` for testing purposes based on that route.

However, `<Route path="/validation" render={() => <p>TestRender</p>} />` does not trigger at all, and I don't understand why.

Here is what I picked up from the React router docs:

[image]

Given that I didn't configure my `<Route>` to be `exact`, I don't quite see how I am different to the example.

Can you point me to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a problem with `/Logon/`. Try the following instead:

```js
<Route path="/Logon/validation" render={() => <p>TestRender</p>} />
```

Alternatively, you can set the [`basename`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) property in the `*Router` component call (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196448/can-i-set-a-base-route-in-react-router)).

Comment: Thanks, that works. Do you know why the /Logon/ is required?

Comment: Because that is the url you want to catch.
But it seems like you can globally set this prefix: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

Comment: Ah, I must have missed that. Thanks!