# How to serve static react app with nginx from location /app

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

I am trying to build and serve react app with webpack and nginx.

```
location /app {
  alias /var/www/react-app;
}
```

And I am using React router

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path = '/'>
    <MainComponent/>
  </Route>

  <Route exact path = '/another'>
    <AnotherComponent/>
  </Route>

...
```

Dev server works as expected, but deploying to nginx I only get blank page.
Adding `/app` to all routes: `exact path = '/app/xxx'` and runnning production build fixes the problem for production build.

How can I automate this using webpack/nginx?

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196448/can-i-set-a-base-route-in-react-router